# Plug-in for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I am developing a plug-in for eclipse for JSHOP2 language. For that i made a plug-in project with 'editor'. I have written the code for the neceessary syntax highlighting for JSHOP2 but I don't know how to integrate this types of plug-in with eclipse and then how to take use of it, so that while i write the JSHOP2 code the necessary syntax gets highlighted. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

So you have an editor that works correctly? 
Then you need to make sure the files with your extension are opened with your editor. That is described [in the Eclipse wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_create_my_own_editor?). 
To make sure your plugin is integrated to your version of Eclipse, either create an update site and import the plugin as you would do with any other plugin. Or export the plugin to a jar and copy the jar to the `dropins` catalog.

Comment: Instead of copying the jar to the dropins category (that is not supported by the update team :) ), you should export your plug-in into your host Eclipse. For that, the deployable plug-ins and fragments wizard offers the Install into host option.

Comment: @Fredrik I have copied the files to the dropind folder but when i tried to open a file with the extension that i have mentioned in my plugin.xml file i have encountered an error--------------------"Could not open the editor: The editor class could not be instantiated. This usually indicates a missing no-arg constructor or that the editor's class name was mistyped in plugin.xml." Please tell me a way out

Comment: @veer01singh I cant debug your code for you, but the error message seemed pretty straightforward: "a missing no-arg constructor", "editor's class name was mistyped in plugin.xml".

Comment: Thank you Mr. fredrik and Zoltan for helping me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using eclipse to write java code (plug-in project). Create a new eclipse launch configuration. Menu Run -> Run Configuration. Location eclipse application. Right click -> Create new & Run. Hope this helps.